# How to avoid high-pitched noise when reversing a chassis fan direction?

Tags: fan, cooling, noise, chassis

I have two Zalman ZF8025CSR (80mm, 12V) computer case fans. Both fans were originally installed (not by me) as *outflow* fans at the front and at the back of the chassis. After reading some Internet advice I decided to move the front fan to the side and physically turn it in the opposite direction to make it an *inflow* fan. In terms of cooling this really helped - shaved several °C off the temperature of the computer components.

However I noticed a high-pitched noise/whine that can be stopped by manually stopping the rotation of the newly reversed fan. Upon further testing I discovered that this noise appears and steeply grows when the inflow-directed fan's blades approach a grating with circular holes on the chassis side or another grating with rectangular (45°-rotated) holes on the chassis front. The maximum noise level is when the inflow fan is attached to and touches the grating. There is no such noise when the fan approaches or is attached to one of the gratings in its original reverse position (outflow). Furthermore, the other fans in my computer make it so that stopping the outflow fan manually doesn't audibly affect the combined PC noise.

Note: both Zalman fans are in "Silent" mode as they utilize noiseless connectors that reduce their speed to 1600-1700 rpm. However the slower rotation in the Silent mode does not prevent this high-pitched noise from an inflow-directed fan.

So my question is: how can I reverse the fan direction while avoiding this extra noise? If this is not possible, I wonder: do other people tolerate such noise from their inflow fans or do they use somewhat different fans or chassis holes?

**EDIT**: Photos of fan directions and chassis gratings:

1. Noisy inflow near circular holes (chassis side panel) [image: Noisy inflow near circular holes]
2. Silent outflow near circular holes (chassis side panel) [image: Silent outflow near circular holes]
3. Rectangular holes with the same issue, perhaps slightly quieter (chassis front panel) [image: Rectangular front panel holes]

Comment: Have you tried something like gluing a piece of paper over the circular holes? Also could you add a picture of the setup in question to your original post so that we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: Just tried attaching a sheet of paper to the side of the grating other than the one, to which the fan is attached. The noise remains, though it becomes lower-pitched. I don't think this is a viable solution as the holes must be open for the air to flow in. Added photos to the question.

Comment: does it whine if you have it powered but unmounted (eg is the whistle in part the case itself)? Fans are mechanical parts that must fight friction to work, so every second they are alive, they are dying little by little. it may be time to experiment with a new one.

Comment: No, neither the fan nor the case whine on their own, even though everything is powered/on/rotating. The noise appears only when the rotating fan blades approach the holes on the case. I think the fan is alright. I just recently cleaned and greased it.

Comment: then I'd guess its either whistling because its pulling air though the case holes (which really doesn't look like it should be the case), or its harmonizing with the case. some kind of rubber washer would fix the latter. that's my guess anyway.

Comment: Today I disassembled my PSU and tried to move its 120mm fan to the round-hole grating: there is a similar noise. So the issue is probably not in the fans themselves.
I attach the fan using silicone pins that were supplied with the fan. I guess that is similar to a rubber washer, but the noise is present.
I've tried to put pieces of plastic between each pin and the case to increase the distance between the fan and the grating. This reduced the noise, but not completely eliminated it - just like manual distance adjustment while holding the fan in my hands affects the noise level.